# issue on web scraping and html

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape this website :"https://www.sipsa-filaha.com/fr/exposant/" . Web scraping is done with Python using Jupyter Notebook, and the code I'm using runs, but it gives me an empty database that only contains columns and no rows. I don't know what the problem is.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

data = []
max_pages = 30  # Change this to the number of pages you want to scrape

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3"
}

for page in range(1, max_pages + 1):
    print("Page", page)
    url = f"https://www.sipsa-filaha.com/fr/exposant/?page={page}"
    
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        response.raise_for_status()  # Check for any request errors
        
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
        
        for exhibitor in soup.select(".exposant-list-item"):
            name = exhibitor.select_one(".title").get_text(strip=True)
            sector = exhibitor.select_one(".secteur-activite").get_text(strip=True)
            services_products = exhibitor.select_one(".services-produits").get_text(strip=True)
            country = exhibitor.select_one(".country").get_text(strip=True)
            contacts = exhibitor.select_one(".contact").get_text(strip=True)
            
            data.append((name, sector, services_products, country, contacts))
        
        time.sleep(2)  # Add a delay of 2 seconds between requests
        
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print("An error occurred:", e)
        break

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Name", "Sector", "Services/Products", "Country", "Contacts"])

excel_file_path = r"C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\scraping_sante\sipsa_exhibitors_data.xlsx"
df.to_excel(excel_file_path, index=False)
print("Data saved to Excel:", excel_file_path)
```

This website contains exhibitors of an event called SIPSA, and I want to scrape a database that includes all exhibitors with their sector of activity, country, services or products, and their contacts. However, my code generates an empty database with only columns, and no rows are being populated.

Comment: probably a site blocked from wb scraping....

Comment: @ D.L  no i Don't think , probanly an issue is in my code

Comment: `soup.select(".exposant-list-item")` << this is giving you an empty list. So check if the selector is correct.

Comment: I recommand you check if the selector is in the source-view (ctrl+u in the page). If the selector is generated with JavaScript, you will not be able to scrap it with bs4.

Comment: I am beginner in html and web scraping and i can't know if the selector is true or not ,can you help me to do this

Comment: @rochard4u The javascript issue isn't because of bs4, it's because of `requests`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example how you could load the different pages and then get the info from the companies:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

ajax_url = "https://www.sipsa-filaha.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"

data = {
    "action": "jet_smart_filters",
    "provider": "jet-engine/exposantlistinggrid",
    "settings[lisitng_id]": "10574",
    "settings[columns]": "3",
    "settings[columns_tablet]": "",
    "settings[columns_mobile]": "2",
    "settings[is_archive_template]": "yes",
    "settings[post_status][]": "publish",
    "settings[use_random_posts_num]": "",
    "settings[posts_num]": "6",
    "settings[max_posts_num]": "9",
    "settings[not_found_message]": "No data was found",
    "settings[is_masonry]": "",
    "settings[equal_columns_height]": "yes",
    "settings[use_load_more]": "",
    "settings[load_more_id]": "",
    "settings[load_more_type]": "click",
    "settings[load_more_offset][unit]": "px",
    "settings[load_more_offset][size]": "0",
    "settings[loader_text]": "",
    "settings[loader_spinner]": "",
    "settings[use_custom_post_types]": "",
    "settings[custom_post_types]": "",
    "settings[hide_widget_if]": "",
    "settings[carousel_enabled]": "",
    "settings[slides_to_scroll]": "1",
    "settings[arrows]": "true",
    "settings[arrow_icon]": "fa fa-angle-left",
    "settings[dots]": "",
    "settings[autoplay]": "true",
    "settings[autoplay_speed]": "5000",
    "settings[infinite]": "true",
    "settings[center_mode]": "",
    "settings[effect]": "slide",
    "settings[speed]": "500",
    "settings[inject_alternative_items]": "",
    "settings[scroll_slider_enabled]": "",
    "settings[scroll_slider_on][]": ["desktop", "tablet", "mobile"],
    "settings[custom_query]": "",
    "settings[custom_query_id]": "",
    "settings[_element_id]": "exposantlistinggrid",
    "props[found_posts]": "447",
    "props[max_num_pages]": "30",
    "props[page]": "1",
    "props[query_type]": "posts",
    "props[query_id]": "2",
    "paged": "1",
    "indexing_filters": "[3085,3086,3910]",
}


headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/116.0",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
    "Referer": "https://www.sipsa-filaha.com/fr/exposant/?page=1",
}

for data["paged"] in range(1, 3):
    print("Page", data["paged"])
    print("-" * 80)
    d = requests.post(ajax_url, data=data, headers=headers).json()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(
        d["content"],
        "html.parser",
    )

    for i in soup.select(".jet-listing-grid__item"):
        title = i.select_one(".elementor-heading-title").text
        url2 = i.a["href"]
        soup2 = BeautifulSoup(
            requests.get(url2, headers=headers).content, "html.parser"
        )
        activite = soup2.select_one('h3:-soup-contains("Secteur d\'activité") + p')
        activite = activite.get_text(strip=True) if activite else "-"

        pays = soup2.select_one('h3:-soup-contains("Pays") + p')
        pays = pays.get_text(strip=True) if pays else "-"

        print(f"{title[:30]:<30} {activite[:30]:<30} {pays:<30}")
    print()
```

Prints:

```
Page 1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2M INDUSTRIES – SARL           Installations internes et équi Algérie                       
AÇAN METAL İNŞAAT PLASTİK GERİ Composants et matériaux pour b Turquie                       
ACEMO                          -                              France                        
ACQUA AZZURRA SRL              Productions halieutiques (cult Italie                        
AD ASTRA S.R.L.                Aliments et additifs           Italie                        
ADAFER GÜBRE ve Tarım İlaçları Agro fourniture (semences, eng Turquie                       
ADICALES ALGERIE – SARL        Aliments et additifs           Algérie                       
AFKO METAL ALGERIE – SARL      Matériel d’irrigation et pompe Algérie                       
AGENCE NATIONALE DE PROMOTION  Divers, organismes et conseils Algérie                       
AGRANA FRUIT ALGERIA – SPA     Fabrication de produits alimen Algérie                       
AGRI DIAM – SARL               Aliments et additifs           Algérie                       
AGRI MAX – SARL                Agro fourniture (semences, eng Algérie                       
AGRISSEM IMPORT EXPORT – SARL  Matériel d’irrigation et pompe Algérie                       
AGRITECHNICA – DLG SERVICE GMB Divers, organismes et conseils Allemagne                     
Agritubel                      -                              France                        

Page 2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AGRO ALIMENTAIRE ACTIVITE SPA  Agro fourniture (semences, eng Alger                         
AGRO BOVINE SERVICES – SARL    Installations internes et équi Algérie                       
AGRO PLUS ALGERIE – SARL       Fabrication des aliments du bé Algérie                       
AGROCAN TARIMSAL ÜRÜNLER SAN V Matériel d’irrigation et pompe Turquie                       
AGRODIV – Filiale Céréales Cen Transformation céréalière -pro Algérie                       
AGROESPACE – SARL              Matériel d’irrigation et pompe Algérie                       
AGROSOUF                       Divers, organismes et conseils Algérie                       
AGRYA ZEMZEM                   Agro fourniture (semences, eng Algérie                       
AIREE – SARL                   Productions végétales, valoris Algérie                       
AIRLAB – SARL                  Hygiène, surveillance, équipem Algérie                       
AIT HELLAL RAHIM – IDURAR      -                              Algérie                       
AKRAM INVESTISSEMENT – SARL    Composants et matériaux pour b Algérie                       
AKUAKARE DIŞ TİCARET A.Ş.      Équipements et accessoires pou Turquie                       
AL BARAKA BANK                 Divers, organismes et conseils Algérie                       
AL SALAM BANK ALGERIA SPA      Divers, organismes et conseils Algérie
```

Comment: And if I want to scrape their services or products, and their contacts as well,and i want the final result will be an Excel spreadsheet.

Comment: @Wiam.07Lazazi That I leave to you. Just get more info from the page, put all info into the final list, create a dataframe as final step and save it as xls.

Comment: @ Andrej Kesely i know how to save it as xls , the problem with me is i am not good at html always I'm making mistakes on it

Comment: @Wiam.07Lazazi It's all trial and error, everybody makes mistakes. Try to get the info you want from the page (and you will learn more about HTML scraping too)

Comment: @ Andrej Kesely okay i  will try thank you for helping me and I am grateful to you